# How can I pass longlistselector data between xaml pages

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried to pass longlistselector data between xaml pages. But it does not work.

How can I pass data using query string or any other possible solution. Please help me

**I tried this code:**

```
public class PaymentItem
    {
        public string Home { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
    public class PaymentList : ObservableCollection<PaymentItem>
    {
        public PaymentList()
        {
            Add(new PaymentItem { Home = "Home", FirstName = "Kevin", LastName = "Peter", Address = "paris", Code = "23343", City = "France" });
        }
    }

    private void imgEditdAddress_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        PaymentItem dataItem = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as PaymentItem;
```

**I have doubt in this part**
I want to pass dataItem values to another edit page

```
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("ModifiedAddress.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Querystrings cannot be used with a user defined object as it stores a single variable only.

You can store a user defined object in IsolatedStorage Application settings

save your object Just before Doing the navgation

```
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] = dataItem;
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

and on second page OnNavigatedTo Handler Just get the object back

```
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State") == true)
 {
 var object= IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] as PaymentItem;
 //Remove the state now
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("State");
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You navigate with some sort of relevant piece of information in navigation query.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ModifiedAddress.xaml?paymentId=1", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then on the SomePage parse that Id, and get the PaymentItem from some sort of your repository...

It's hard to give more information based on the code you gave.

The second option (a bit worse) is to share the item through App class, which can be accessed from all the pages really.

Answer (score 0):

To add some options to Aman's answer:

you can also pass variables to the site by navigation events. You can do it by overriding the OnNavigatedFrom event of the page and adding an accessible property to the page you want to pass something to.

example:

```
Page1.xaml.cs

protected override OnNavigatedFrom(...args... e)
{
   if(e.Uri.OriginalString.Contains("Page2.xaml"))
   {
      ((Page2)e.Content).SourceList = Page1LongListSelector.ItemSource;
   }
}
```

Then Page2:

```
Page2.xaml.cs

public List<SomeObject> SourceList
{
    get;
    set;
}

....
Page2LongListSelector.ItemSource = SourceList;
....
```

This can be done because the OnNavigatedFrom event is called AFTER the navigation was done and the second page is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the data in the page you are navegating with OnNavigatedTo method.

read this article to understand how it works:

[How to pass data between pages in Windows Phone: Alternatives](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives)

And after download this example to explore the code:

[Passing Data between Pages](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Passing-Data-between-Pages-958ee09b)

Hope Helps! Greetings!